# Ruby messages to self

Tags: ruby

If I run the following Ruby code:

```
class Foo

  def foo=(something)
    puts "It's a #{something}"
  end

  def foo_assign
    self.foo = "bar"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.foo_assign
```

The output is: `It's a bar`.

On the other hand, if I run the code:

```
class Foo

  def foo=(something)
    puts "It's a #{something}"
  end

  def foo_assign
    foo = "bar"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.foo_assign
```

There is no output. How can that be given that `foo` and `self.foo` are equivalent?

Comment: `foo =` is a local variable assigning.

Comment: @Ilya Does that mean that I need an explicit receiver for the assignment method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo = "bar"` is ambiguous in the `foo_assign` method. Ruby thinks you are trying to assign a local variable and not call the method, so that's what it does for you. (imagine setting `bar = "foo"` on the next line, it would still work, even though there is no `bar=` method). In cases where it's ambiguous what you are trying to do or call, you have to use `self.`. Someone better than I might be able to explain this all better or more clearly, but that's what is happening here.

Comment: Well explained. Thank you!